# Check of Time In (Attendance c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, time-and-attendance

I am making a small program where an employee will time in/out.
The employee has an Employee ID and that is the one that must be used in order to time in and out.

Timing in is okay but my problem here is that the employee can time in a lot of times without timing out.

What I am trying to do is that whenever the employee times in, he/she is not allowed to time in again, unless he/she times out.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
private void TimeIN()
    {
        //check if Employee ID belongs to the tbl_humans table

        Connection();
        sql_connect.Close();
        sql_connect.Open();
        sql_command = new MySqlCommand("Select * from tbl_humans where ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "' ;", sql_connect);

        sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();

        string username;
        //string password;

        username = (textBox1.Text);
        // password = (textBox2.Text);

        int count = 0;

        while (sql_reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }


        //checks if the Employee ID has been already timed in on tbl_loginout
        // if it's already timed in, it will display "You time out first"
        // but unfortunately, it's not working and still continues to time in the employee even if the employee is already timed in

        if (count == 0) 
        {
           try
           {
               Connection();
               sql_connect.Close();
               sql_connect.Open();


               sql_command = new MySqlCommand
                   ("Select * from tbl_loginout where ID = '" + textBox1.Text +
                   "' and timein_date = '" + DateTime.Today.ToString() + // checks if the employee is timed in on that day(today)
                   "' and timeout_time = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("00:00:00") + // checks if the employee is still not time out
                   "';", sql_connect);
               sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();

               MessageBox.Show("You Time Out first");
           }

           catch (Exception aa)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(aa.Message);
           }
       }
```

A help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand. What is wrong with this code exactly? BTW, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Actually, there's nothing wrong. I only want to achieve that whenever the employee times in, he/she must time out first if he/she will time in again. But it's not happening. And about parameterized queries, I am still learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `"' and timeout_time = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("00:00:00") + "';"` from your query or replace it with `"' and timeout_time = null;"`.

In general, you should write an SQL you want to use by hand and execute it directly to make sure it returns what you want.

One more comment: you execute the reader `sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();` and don't do anything with the result, you just show the message box no matter what the real result is.